# how to submit a form based on any input with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I listen to all inputs in a form so when there is an input on any of the form fields, it submits the form.

The Form fields could be a checkbox, text_field or anything of sort. I am not a javascript expert. Thanks for your help

**Example**

```
$(function(){
    $('#new_search_form').on('...', function(){
       $(this).closest('form').submit();
    });    
});
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: Use `.serialize()` http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: Depending on internet speed, this might not be a pleasurable experience for the user.   It's a lot of postbacks.

Comment: yes i no. but my client is requesting for it. I tried so hard but if there is any other solution you know about pls let me no. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you're pretty close with what you already have!

The property of on() that helps is the one called "change"

```
$(function(){
    $('#search').on('change', function(){
       alert("submit");
    });
})
```

Here's a jfiddle that calls an alert everytime something changes! http://jsfiddle.net/nMPbp/1/

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function(){
    $('#new_search_form').on('change',function(){
       $(this).closest('form').submit();
    })
})
```

This one will fire if **ANYTHING** on the form is changed including textareas, radios, checkboxes, inputs, selects.

Comment: It may be worth noting that if it's a text input, this will only fire when the input loses focus

Comment: With this symbol * the requested result from the form was received four times.

Comment: Four submits? Wow... I guess it's being a bit too persistent. I've edited.

Answer (score 1):

Try using 'change' event like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#new_search_form').on('change', 'input', function(){
       $(this).closest('form').submit();
    })    
})
```

Comment: Note: `<textarea>` is NOT considered an input element.